# How do I capture filter information from a DataPilot table?

Tags: openoffice-calc, pivot-table

In OpenOffice Calc, how do I capture filter information from a DataPilot table?

Specifically, I have a DataPilot table which I graph on a chart, filtering on a field not appearing in the table.

I want the value of that filter (either its `foo=bar AND baz=xyzzy` or at least the "bar" and "xyzzy") to be visible on-screen – perhaps in a cell – along with the chart. (Even better would be to have it in the title of the chart, but that's probably too much to ask.)

How can I do this?